# Find max from first row to current row in Kusto (Timeseries)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to find out how to extend a column to show the max value looking back from the first row to the current row (e.g. looping through the table from the row with the earliest timestamp to the latest).

Here's a sample input table:

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Count:int)
[
   datetime(2021-01-01), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-02), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-03), 2,
   datetime(2021-01-04), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-05), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-06), 3,
   datetime(2021-01-07), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-08), 2,
];
```

The desired output is:

| Timestamp | Count | MaxToDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-06 | 3 | 3 |
| 2021-01-07 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-08 | 2 | 3 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `scan` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator

for example:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Count:int)
[
   datetime(2021-01-01), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-02), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-03), 2,
   datetime(2021-01-04), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-05), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-06), 3,
   datetime(2021-01-07), 1,
   datetime(2021-01-08), 2,
]
| order by Timestamp asc
| scan declare (max_to_date:int = 0) with 
(
    step s1: true => max_to_date = case(Count > s1.max_to_date,
                                        Count,
                                        s1.max_to_date);
)
```

| Timestamp | Count | max_to_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 3 |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Yoni! Once I've got the minimum reputation I'll upvote this.

Comment: Andrew - you should mark it as an answer, I believe that you can do it with the current reputation